# SQL Server 2000 "Select is broken" with TOP clause

Tags: sql-server, select

Using SQL Server 2000 Developer Edition, why would this code:

```
select top 10 * from table
```

result in this error:

> Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '10'.

and this code:

```
select * from master m
left join locality l on m.localityid = l.localityid
```

result in this error:

> Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1,
>   Line 2 Line 2: Incorrect syntax near
>   'left'.

Comment: Do you receive the error from SSMS?  In a fresh window containing no other queries?

Comment: damn, the downvotes here are quick.  i tried to suggest a TOP 10 with an ORDER BY. it was quickly downvoted.  i'll just post my answer on comment.  put an ORDER BY on your TOP 10, putting a TOP 10 without an ORDER BY have an undetermined result anyway, won't makes much sense

Comment: so.. adding an ORDER BY is strongly suggested for TOP operations, even if ORDERBY-less TOP would spit out results.

Comment: I found the answer in the end - answered my own question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was database compatibility.  It was set to 60, and should have been 80.

Here's an extract from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

> The value must be one of the following:
>   - 80 = SQL Server 2000
>   - 90 = SQL Server 2005
>   - 100 = SQL Server 2008

I changed it to 80 and all is well, now.

Comment: I guessed, and found the option in the database properties in Enterprise Manager. :)

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why this would break, it might be due to a setup or compatibility issue with the installation. How are you running the queries? From Query Analyser?

As a couple of quick suggestions though, try putting the 10 in brackets. SELECT TOP (10) * FROM ..... Also, try aliasing your tables using the AS keyword. e.g. SELECT * FROM master AS m ...

Comment: TOP (10) shouldn't work in 2000. Parentheses are a 2005+ thing.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries should work nothing wrong there. Are you executing from the Query Analyzer?

I can reproduce the errors if i select only "SELECT TOP 10" from the first query and "SELECT * FROM MASTER M LEFT" for the second. So if you aren't executing from the Query Analyzer, maybe your querystring gets altered in code in you application somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

the queries have no problem. which query analyzer are you using (as MSDE has no GUI)?